# Selenium - where do pip install locate chromedriver.exe?

Tags: python, linux, selenium

I am on Raspberry Pi (Linux), and I'm trying to launch my Python program, but it prompts me an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I know that I need to set `PATH = /location`, but the problem is that I can't locate the chromedriver.exe file, so my question is, where should this be located?
I downloaded selenium by doing `pip3 install selenium` and i searched my whole `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` folder but I can't seem to find it.

Should I just put my whole site-packages as a path - wouldn't that be quite risky and stupid?

Comment: you need to place driver in path that is listed inside python program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion from https://askubuntu.com/questions/539498/where-does-chromedriver-install-to I was able to make it work like this:

Installed the chromium-chromedriver:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

Adding the path to the selenium line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
OR
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Note that this opens Chromium and not Chrome. Hope it was helpful.

Comment: I will try that. You wrote 'OR' and wrote the same thing twice though - that wasn't intentional was it?

Comment: my bad . i fixed it